# Should 0xABCD - 0x1234 set the carry bit?

Tags: math, assembly, carryflag, pic24

I was studying for my final when I came across this question here:

[image: question]

After going through it, I got an answer of 0x9999 because when you perform the subtraction via 2's complement, there is a carry on the MSB, so the branch instruction would send the program to loc1. My professor says the answer is 0x9997, which is only possible if the carry bit is not set. I've looked it up and it seems like the carry bit should have been set here. Am I missing something or did my professor make a mistake?

Comment: Doesn't Microchip's development tools include a simulator/emulator? That would probably be the easiest way to verify this.

Comment: I agree with your solution, ABCD-1234 produces no borrow, which in PIC means C=1 so the jump is taken and the result should indeed be 9999.

Comment: @lurker : in the case of PIC (and some processors - like the 6502) the carry flag on subtraction means *not borrow*. The document you have assumes an environment where the reverse is true.